# afterShow event on jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the date picker component of jQuery UI 1.12.0. I want to change the `z-index` after someone clicks in the textbox and the date picker is through showing.

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/6qowd13k/5/)

I have tried adding the below, but really don't understand what the `_updateDatepicker_original` and `_updateDatepicker` are:

```
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
        var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
        if (afterShow)
            afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));
    }
```

I call this like:

```
$('.AddDatePicker').datepicker({
    afterShow: function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', '1000001');
    }
});
```

However, the `z-index` does not change until I change the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css for that without touching the javascript using

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-widget {
    z-index: 3 !important;
}
```

Another option is to use the `beforeShow` callback in order to add a specific class to the datepicker:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.AddDatePicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(el, inst) {
      inst.dpDiv.addClass('zin')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.itw {
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.zin {
  z-index: 3 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" id="dtp" class="AddDatePicker" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="intheway" class="itw" />
```

Comment: my intention is to use javascript I did find a solution and also figured out what the _updateDatepicker was referring to. Thanks.

Comment: Well, basically you can always set the datepicker with a specific class/id and use css there... imho it will be much better

Comment: The datepicker does have a specific class in my example `.AddDatePicker` but I noticed that in the rendered markup when the datepicker is created jquery appends the div containing (`id="ui-datepicker-div"`) the datepicker to the form so it is a little more tricky to apply the css to that specific datepicker

Comment: @Popo You can always use the `beforeShow` callback for that: https://jsfiddle.net/xLy7jqky/

Comment: applying the z-index does work the same as a color for some reason https://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/4rb4ofL1/2/ however, if you use the stupid setTimeOut function it will work. Granted using an existing event is better than having to override and create the afterShow event

Comment: Actually it works exactly the same, you just need to add the `!important` to override the inline style: https://jsfiddle.net/4rb4ofL1/3/

Comment: I like that, update your answer and I will give you credit. :)

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Adding a setting a time out to nothing allows the css to be changed on the first firing of the _updateDatepicker event. After more research I discovered that _updateDatepicker  is an event with the jquery ui source code:

```
/* Generate the date picker content. */
    _updateDatepicker: function( inst ) {...
```

my solution:

```
 $('.AddDatePicker').datepicker({
            beforeShow: function () {                
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', '1000001');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
```