# jQuery DatePicker: Prevent the "Today" button from being grayed out

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is related to post [jQuery UI Datepicker Today Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139237/jquery-ui-datepicker-today-link)

Using the code below results in the "Today" button being rendered in black. However, it only works once because when the "Today" button is clicked it goes back to being grayed out. Is there a better way to handle this so that the color rendering is permanent?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datePicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    yearRange: "2000:c+1",
    showButtonPanel: true
  });

 $('.datePicker').click(function () {
        $('button.ui-datepicker-current').removeClass('ui-priority-secondary').addClass('ui-priority-primary');
  });
});
```

**Update:** https://jsfiddle.net/megoo1xk/14/

Comment: Have you tried just creating a style for `ui-priority-secondary` (so it overrdes the one in jquery-ui css)?

Comment: i think you can create fiddle so ever1 can try it live

Comment: I have added the Fiddle. @Stephen, I am trying to avoid overriding the CSS in the event updates come out in the future. I'm trying to see if there is any other way to resolve the issue.

Comment: All you need is to include your own style sheet that styles it (I did not mean alter the jquery ui style sheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since datepicker only have beforeShow event instead onShow, onOpen or afterShow. We should build it by ourself.

```
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
  $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
    var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
    if (afterShow)
      afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));
  }
```

Reference: [afterShow event on jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013512/aftershow-event-on-jquery-datepicker)

if we join with your function, that will be like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/megoo1xk/50/)